# Comparing Old and new value of the record

Tags: salesforce, apex

Hope you are all doing good!!!.

I just need to fix this one and I googled the logic and when I tried I got an error and then I have copied the online code and paste that too but no use.

the logic of the below code is :**Check the phone number of the account and compare old and new value of the phone number if it's not the same value then I need to update the old value in the description.**

```
public class CheckOldAndNewValueonAccount {
public static void accNewOldValues(List<Account> accList){
    for(Account acc: accList){
        Account oldAcc = Trigger.oldMap.get(acc.Id); 
        if(acc.Phone != oldAcc.Phone){
            acc.Description = 'Old Phone number this account is :'+oldAcc.Phone;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Error: **Illegal assignment from SObject to Account.**

Please guide me on this.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is this line:

`Account oldAcc = Trigger.oldMap.get(acc.Id);`

I believe the type of old map is `Map<String, sObject>`.

`sObject` is a type that is a Salesforce object (any one) but none specifically.

So you are trying to assign an sObject to a variable you are declaring as an Account type.

You can just do the following:

`sObject oldAcc = Trigger.oldMap.get(acc.Id);`

unless you specifically want to try and cast the sObject to an Account (concrete) type. I don't see any major benefit to doing so. Let us know if that was the problem and if this resolved it.

Edit: see this trailhead:

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_database/apex_database_sobjects

Section: Casting Generic sObjects to Specific sObject Types

You can easily cast to Account. There is a snippet there.

Dot notation is not available on generic sObject types.

Or you can use `.get('fieldname')` which works on generic sObject as well.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response and Yes I tried sObject instead of Account but in the next step ie., if(acc.Phone != oldAcc.Phone) when checking the condition it shows like Variable does not exist: Phone.
The exact logic is to capture and save the previous value in one field.

Comment: trigger.oldMap.get(acc.Phone) != trigger.newMap.get(acc.Phone) It works.

Comment: I think that is a mistake. That should always be equal, I think.